# needed to form a different classes for tkinter to execute

Tags: python, tkinter

I am writing a software the total work has been done completely but all code has been done in single class, initially defining the method was normal as they increases the naming is confusing .
so needed some help

initial imports

```
from tkinter import *
from ttkthemes import themed_tk as tk
```

defined class

```
class Main_page:
    """Main Window this is configuration that exist when opens"""

    def __init__(self, window):
        self.window = window
        self.window.geometry("1366x768+0+0")
        self.window.title("Admin Page")
        self.window.config(bg="gray")

        """Creating window in full screen"""
        self.window.attributes("-fullscreen", True)
        self.window.bind('<Escape>', lambda event: self.window.attributes("-fullscreen", False))
        self.window.bind('<F11>', lambda event: self.window.attributes("-fullscreen", True))

        self.top_fra()
        self.lef_fra()
        self.body_fra()

    def top_fra(self):
        """This is top Frame in exist on all pages"""
        top_frame = Frame(self.window, height=70, width=1340)
        top_frame.place(x=10, y=10)

    def lef_fra(self):
        """This is side frame where the main handling buttons are placed
        as billing, transaction details , settings"""
        lef_frame = Frame(self.window, height=610, width=125, borderwidth=0)
        lef_frame.place(x=10, y=85)

        # Billing Button for left side
        billing = Button(lef_frame, text="Billing", width=10, height=5, bg="gray", command=self.billing_page)
        billing.place(x=25, y=20)

        # manage Button for left side
        manage = Button(lef_frame, text="Bill \n Manage", width=10, height=5, bg="gray",
command=self.bill_manage)
        manage.place(x=25, y=140)

    def body_fra(self):
        """This is body frame where the initial info handles"""
        self.body_frame = Frame(self.window, width=1210, height=610, bg="white")
        self.body_frame.place(x=140, y=85)
```

now the two required classes are defined as follows methods and every time the destroy method should be called to smoothly run the program

```
    def billing_page(self):
        """when billing button is selected , the initial view of the page is opened"""
        self.body_frame.destroy()

        self.body_frame = Frame(self.window, width=1210, height=610, bg="White")
        self.body_frame.place(x=140, y=85)

    def bill_manage(self):
        """this is bills managing page where we get
         all the bills details hear"""

        """this is placed because when repeatedly called the billing page or 
        bill manager page the frames become more and we see some lags in execution"""
        self.body_frame.destroy()

        self.body_frame = Frame(self.window, width=1210, height=610, bg="blue")
        self.body_frame.place(x=140, y=85)


def win():
    """initial initialization the page to view"""
    window = tk.ThemedTk()
    window.get_themes()
    window.set_theme("black")
    Main_page(window)
    window.mainloop()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    win()
```

can we convert the of dine the billing_page method and bill_manage method in separate classes and can work on those further

Comment: maybe you should hide (`place_forget()`) and unhide (again `place()`) object instead of `destroy` and `create` it again.

Comment: but when we click billing again seems it will create new window again na

Comment: it need to create all frames at start - one for  `billing_page` and one for `bill_manage` - and later use only `place_forget()` to hide one frame, and `place` to show another. This method is very useful  because if you put some value in one frame then you can get them after hiding (you can get them after destroy) and when you show frame again then you see again the same values.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can inherit the Main_page class in the new class, like

```
Class NewOne(Main_page):
def __init__(self):
 pass

def billing_page(self):
 # your code
```

Comment: ```billing_page() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'```getting this error